# json query and json path

Tags: json, syntax, jsonpath

I try not to make this a loaded question, but a quite focused one instead --

when talking about processing JSON data, I thought people have converged, from [different fancy ways to query json structures](http://orangevolt.blogspot.ca/2012/12/8-ways-to-query-json-structures.html), to just [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), AKA JPath, "[*proposed by Stefan Goessner allows for XPath-like expressions to be evaluated against JSON*](http://dev-answers.blogspot.ca/2013/07/querying-json-using-jsonpath.html)".

At least I thought so, until I take a closer look today at the syntax of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which looks quite similar to JPath, but *actually different*, and more *advanced*.

So, my question is, any one knows **where its syntax is coming from** (as `jq` doesn't say so on its web site)?

Further, it doesn't say what **jq** stands for either. So let me assume it stands for "json query". So the **next question** is, of all json query tool listed in [jsonquerytool.com](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/), (i.e., JSONPath, JSPath, Lodash, Underscore, JPath, XPath for JSON, JSON Pointer and just plain old JavaScript),

[image: json query tool]

whose syntax are **closer to JPath**, and whose 
are **closer to `jq`**, or their syntax are just "all-over-the-places", i.e., each are quite different from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to this question is "all-over-the-places". There must be dozens of JSON Query languages proposed and implemented now. jq is *very* popular in Data Science. It also has an online sandbox at https://jqplay.org/

I was unaware of recent clampdown on SO questions so I asked a general Q about this topic and got shut down. No surveys, no off site refs allowed. [JSON Query in 2018: most used languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018158/json-query-in-2018-most-used-languages)

Stack-O data science geeks ought to try a tally up and report of the JSON Query languages. Right now it's the wild kingdom.

2 others not on your list are JSONiq and XPath 3.1. Xpath (along with XQuery) is a W3 standard. JSON was created in part as a lean replacement for XML so I think they are nearly isomorphic so far as data structures.